# Why do I get a Bad File Descriptor error when writing to opened File?

Tags: rust

Calling `write_all` on a file returns an error with the description: `os error`. Debug printing the error outputs: `Err(Error { repr: Os(9) })`

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include any code, so I had to make wild guesses about what you are doing. Here's one piece of code that reproduces your error:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut f = fs::File::open("/").unwrap();

    // f.write_all(b"hello").unwrap();
    // Error { repr: Os(9) }

    match f.write_all(b"hello") {
        Ok(..) => {},
        Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
    }
    // Bad file descriptor (os error 9)
}
```

If you use the [`Display`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/trait.Display.html) (`{}`) format instead of [`Debug`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/trait.Debug.html) (`{:?}`), you will see an error message that is nicer than just the error code. Note that `unwrap` will use the `Debug` formatter, so you have to use `match` in this case.

You could also [look up the error code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h) in the kernel source. You don't indicate if you are running Windows (unlikely), OS X or Linux, so I guessed Linux.

There are [lots of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=errno+9) that then explain what the code can mean, but I'm sure you know how to search through those, now that you have a handle on the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Using the Display format rather than the Debug to get more detailed information hadn't occurred to me.