# Why am I getting a "bad file descriptor" error when writing file in rust?

Tags: rust

Ignoring the fact that I'm using `unwrap` to ignore what happens if the file doesn't exist, it seems to me like this short bit of code should work (as long as the file does exist):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("test.txt").unwrap();
    let result = f.write_all(b"some data");

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Data written successfully"),
        Err(e) => panic!("Failed to write data: {}", {e}),
    }
}
```

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to write data: Bad file descriptor (os error 9)', src/main.rs:10:19
```

To be clear, I know if I follow one of the many examples online, I can write to a file. The question isn't "how do I write to a file?". It's why THIS isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a Bad File Descriptor error when writing to opened File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471900/file-io-os-error-codes)

Comment: @pretzelhammer I agree that they're both about "os error 9", but that answer doesn't actually address that, nor provide a solution for the issue. Which is understandable, given the lack of code in that question :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It isn't working because [`File::open()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) open's a file in **read-only mode**. Instead you have to use [`File::create()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) which opens a file in **write-only mode**. Alternatively you can also use [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html), to further specify if you want to [`append()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.append) to a file instead.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::create("test.txt").unwrap();

    let result = f.write_all(b"some data");

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Data written successfully"),
        Err(err) => panic!("Failed to write data: {}", err),
    }
}
```

Using [`File::create()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.create) is the same as using [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) in the following way:

```rust
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut f = OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("test.txt")
        .unwrap();

    let result = f.write_all(b"some data");

    match result {
        Ok(_) => println!("Data written successfully"),
        Err(err) => panic!("Failed to write data: {}", err),
    }
}
```

Comment: documentation is here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl

 thankyou for the explanation